# VBA: Updating date as yyyymmdd coming up with hashes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update the date in the format of 20190715 (yyyymmdd) to column F under the header. My code seems to return hashes and I cannot understand why.

```
lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Value = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
End Sub
```

All the cells populated with the current date in yyyymmdd

Comment: It most probably is an issue with the column width. Please increase the column width or auto-fit the column width. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job?

```vb
Range("F2:F" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd;@"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, It is correct in the formula bar but still showing hashes in the cell

Comment: Did you try column width as suggested above?

Comment: yes when i adjust the column width the hashes still populate the width of the column

Comment: I got it by changing the style of the cells to Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Style = "Normal"

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.